# Add page from HTML file in JSPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf, html2canvas

Good afternoon,
     I'm having trouble with JsPDF, I need to put 4 HTML files in 4 pages of a PDF, each HTML file has the exact size of 1 page for example:

file01.html -> Page 01 of PDF, 
   file02.html -> Page02 of PDF ...,

but I'm not able to do this, I tried to put the 4 HTML in 1 HTML and use addPage (), However, did not work, all the content is on the first page and the other pages are blank.

Does anyone know how I can do this with JsPDF and jQuery?

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4');
    doc.addHTML($('#body'), function() {
    doc.save("teste.pdf");

});
```

});

Comment: show what result u are getting now

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i made a workround creating one pdf for each html file, then merging it